# How to properly set the model when doing CABeginAnimation

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, calayer, cabasicanimation

I have a `UIImageView` that when the user taps it, a border of 4 points toggles on and off.  I'm trying to animate the border in and out as follows:

```
CABasicAnimation *widthAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"borderWidth"];
widthAnimation.toValue = self.isSelected ? @4.0 : @0.0;
widthAnimation.duration = 0.1;
[self.imageView.layer addAnimation:widthAnimation forKey:@"borderWidth"];
```

Now, as I've learned from research and scouring SO, `CABasicAnimation` just changes the presentation layer, but not the actual model.  I've also read that using `fillMode` and `removedOnCompletion` is bad practice, since it leads to inconsistencies between the model and what the user sees.  So, I tried to change the model with the following line:

```
self.imageView.layer.borderWidth = self.isSelected ? 4.0 : 0.0;
```

The problem is, this line seems to set the property straight away, so by the time the animation kicks in, the border width is already at it's desired value.  I've tried sticking this line at the beginning of the code, end, and everywhere in between, but to no success.  I did manage to find a hacky solution: instead of setting the property, I passed the property setter to `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:`, with the delay being the duration of the animation.  This works most of the time, but sometimes the cycles don't quite match up, and the animation will run first, then it jumps back to the original state, then it snaps to the new state, presumably as a result of `performSelector`

So is there any way to smoothly animate a border without `performSelector`?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of CABasicAnimation I made a while ago :

```
-(void) animateProgressFrom:(CGFloat)fromValue to:(CGFloat)toValue
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    animation.fromValue = @(fromValue);
    animation.toValue = @(toValue);
    animation.duration = ABS(toValue - fromValue)*3.0;
    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"opacity"];

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    self.layer.opacity = toValue;
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

I think what you needed is the CATransaction at the end of the layer animation.